# Media Player set path of another folder

Tags: android, eclipse, media-player

I am making a simple app that plays an mp3 file. I use the code

```
mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.mysong);
```

But this works only if my song is saved in the `res\raw` folder of my PC. Sooner or later I will run the app of my iphone (as soon as I buy one!). What happens if I must set the path to the one that the mobile is saved? Let's say my Downloads folder from my mobile phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by giving it it's absolute path from the `ExternalStorage` as follwoing

```
mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,  Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+ "/Music/mysong.mp3"));
```

**OR** Use `setDataSource()` method:

```
String PATH_TO_FILE = "/sdcard/music.mp3";    
mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(PATH_TO_FILE);
mediaPlayer.prepare();   
mediaPlayer.start()
```

Comment: thanks for help. may I ask, what does prepare stand for? From what I have searched, it says that "Successful invoke of this method in a valid state transfers the object to the Prepared state. Calling this method in an invalid state throws an IllegalStateException." but I am having a bit difficult time to understand this. Thanks a lot anyways

Answer (score 0):

```
String filePath = "somepath/somefile.mp3";

MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer.setDataSource(filePath);
mediaPlayer.prepare();
```